# Automated planner

Tags: planning, todo

I'm looking for an app that has the following features:

- I can create a list of tasks. Each task will have an estimated duration (for its completion). Each task might have a due date.
- I should be able to mark my "work" and "non-work" time slots for the near future.
- There should be a "Plan automatically" button which should distribute the tasks into my "work" time slots based on tasks' durations, due dates and also the lengths of my "work" slots.
- After this automatic planning, I should be able to drag-and-drop tasks among my work time slots.

Do you know of any apps like this?

Comment: Cool request. Would you mind adding your OS requirements and your budget?

Comment: Did you find it?

Comment: Yes. Reclaim dot ai. Or usemotion dot com. I like the first one better.